# Excel Number Format Category: Date or Custom? (user input: "1 jan 2020")

Tags: excel

Number Format Category : why it was recognized as custom?

Tested on following platforms

- Excel on Mac (16.37)
- Excel on Windows (version 2002)
- Excel online

My customer is asking a question: When he types ”1 jan 2020” in a cell, Excel recognize and convert to 1-Jan-2020, when you double click the cell, entering the cell edit mode, it value changed to 2020/1/1. 
[image]

However, when checking the number format, it was categorized as custom

[image]

In date category, there is format exactly match what excel present to customer.

[image]

So could someone share some insight why user input “1 jan 2020” is recognized as custom instead of date?

Comment: What version of Excel is it?  I'm on 365 in the UK and that date format only appears in Custom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer: 
if you pick the format you want and then switch to custom, this dialog will show you what formatting codes were used by Excel. In this case the actual date format is `[$-en-US]d-mmm-yy;@` and not the autodetected `d-mmm-yy`.

The difference between the two formats is that `d-mmm-yy` will get localized for different user locales, but `[$-en-US]d-mmm-yy;@` will not. It's tied to English (United States). 
In Windows, it can be changed based on user locale via Win+R -> intl.cpl.

Excel's logic is to get the number format, and then do a linear search through all categories to see it exists anywhere. It will end up in Custom for both formats that are in Custom by default, but also if there was no match found at all. `1 jan 2020` is not categorized as Date - the format is d-mmm-yy which does not match any formats in Data category; it does match a format in Custom category, so it's categorized as Custom.

here is a simple workaround in VBA snipped to the workbook module, new entries will have expected format:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sheet As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    With Sheet
        If Target.NumberFormat = "d-mmm-yy" Then
            Target.NumberFormat = "[$-en-US]d-mmm-yy;@"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```